# how to run asyncio.wait method inside of a sync method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm testing the method `wait` from `asyncio` package inside a `sync` method and trying to get the fastest response from 3 differente endpoints, with:

```
done, pendings = loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
)
```

this code above is working fine but it kills the `feature` of `return_when` because i'm running everything until it completes, how can i use method `wait` inside a `sync` method and get the `FIRST_COMPLETE`?

Comment: How did you conclude that you are running everything until it completes? `run_until_complete` does run until `asyncio.wait` completes, but `return_when` should ensure that it completes when the first task does.

Comment: i've tested with 3 differentes endpoints where each of them have a `time.sleep` with 1, 2 and 3, the code that make the requests print everything in sequence but the final result only shows up after the "3" prints out the result, i'll try to edit my post with the tests

Comment: You can't use `time.sleep` in asyncio code, you need to `await asyncio.sleep(...)` instead. Likewise, you need to use [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) instead of requests.